# how to handle json parse error in actix web when there is no payload in request

Tags: json, rust, actix-web

Hi I am new to rust and I am implementing this minimalist web server. I need to parse a field from payload json and it works. fine if handler has these parameters.

```
async fn handler(req: HttpRequest, route_meta: Data<RouteMeta>, pload: web::Json<UserId>) -> impl Responder {
```

but how to handle requests that don't have payload now i get error

actix_web::types::json] Failed to deserialize Json from payload.
been trying to add this error handling

```
 App::new()      
.app_data(web::JsonConfig::default().error_handler(json_error(JsonPayloadError, "error")))


fn json_error(err:JsonPayloadError, &HttpRequest)-> JsonPayloadError{
    log::info!("error"{}, err)
}
```

keep getting   log::info!("error"{}, err)
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `JsonPayloadError`, found `()`

Comment: Here's an example of handling Json parse errors globally: https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.JsonConfig.html#examples. To handle it on a per case basis, this might work (untested): `pload: Result<web::Json<UserId>, actix_web::error::Error>`.